Instruct spark to use correct authentication provider to access s3 bucket
I have a spark app running on EKS cluster within a K8S pod, we use a serviceAccount pointing to a IAM role to access an S3 bucket.
In the Spark configurations i try to instruct Spark that it should use the WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider as described in this page.
    spark:
          conf:
             spark.hadoop.fs.defaultFS: s3a://MY_BUCKET
  spark.hadoop.fs.s3.customAWSCredentialsProvider:com.amazonaws.auth.WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider
             .......other configs....

..
But when i run the job, when spark tries to connect to the bucket i get an exception returned by S3 with a 401 response code saying no authorization was provided, mentioning also 3 credentials provider i am not using:
Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: MY_BUCKET: org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: No AWS Credentials provided by SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: Unauthorized (Service: null; Status Code: 401; Error Code: null; Request ID: null)

So in my configurations i am clearly stating to use the WebIdentityTokenCredentialsProvider but this is ignored.
Also, when i inspect the pod after failure i see that the serviceaccount mechanism works fine as i see the mountVolumes to the token file:







How can i instruct Spark to use the role instead of trying with SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider, EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider or InstanceProfileCredentialsProvider ?
